# how print an http request contents into a terminal as "cat" does to local files?

Tags: terminal

I would like to print the contents of a web request, similar as "cat" command does for local files.

I tried lynx but it does not simply prints to unix shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the request and print response to console:

```
curl https://serverfault.com
```

Make the request and save response to file:

```
curl https://serverfault.com > output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are looking for `curl`. For details please read the manpage. For examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL#Examples_of_cURL_use_from_command_line